# IEnumerable.Select with index

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
 var accidents = text.Skip(NumberOfAccidentsLine + 1).Take(numberOfAccidentsInFile).ToArray();
```

where accidents is an array of strings.

I want to make a Linq transformation from the string array to an array of Accident objects as follows:

```
 return accidents.Select(t => new Accident() {Id = i, Name = t.Replace("\"", string.Empty)}).ToArray();
```

How do I retrieve the index i from the accidents array using Linq or do I have to go old school?

Comment: Do you want the index from the `accidents` array itself, or the index from the original `text` enumeration? If the former, then Marcin's answer is fine. If the latter, then you will need to do the `Skip()` and `Take()` _after_ the initial `Select()` where the index is introduced.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of index you're looking for, but if it's just set of consecutive numbers then you're lucky. There is `Select` overload that does exactly that:

```
return accidents.Select((t, i) => new Accident() {Id = i, Name = t.Replace("\"", string.Empty)}).ToArray();
```

It expects a delegate that takes two parameters - the item and its index.

Comment: Just a set of consecutive numbers is all I am looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Enumerable.Range to generate the ID values and then use the current value to index into your String Array:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, accidents.Length).Select(f => new Accident() { Id = f, Name = accidents[f] })
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this LINQ query will help you to find The formated name with Index:

```
var accidents=(from acc in accidents
    select new {
        id=accidents.IndexOf(acc),
        Name = acc.Replace("\"", string.Empty)
    }).ToArray()
```

or you can also use `.ToList()` for the case if you want result to be in IEnumerable format.